# How to display or persist a double like 123456789012.123456789012 in Java?

Tags: java

I am  wondering How to display or persist a double like 123456789012.123456789012 in Java without rounding the last decimal digits to 0?

Thanks

Comment: You can't. `double` values only have so much precision. You need to look into using `BigDecimal` instead.

Comment: Thanks. I just wanted to make sure. I will use BigDecimal.

Comment: Just make sure you use the String constructor: `new BigDecimal("123456789012.123456789012")`.